# AWS custom domain mapping with uri parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, custom-domain

I’m using a serverless micro services architecture and have multiple REST API GWs. All APIs are mapped using Custom Domain to a base URL.
For example:
API1 -> api.myDomain.com/v1/items
API2 -> api.myDomain.com/v1/students

We have a new service we would like to map using uri parameters. For example:
API3 ->  api.myDomain.com/v1/students/{id}/classes

Is it possible to do so using custom domain mapping?
If not, is there a work around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using proxy integration, where you select "configure as proxy resource" when creating the resource.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html